# iPhone and mac Connection Via Bonjour

Tags: iphone

In my application i want to export and import files from mac to iphone.when i start a application in iPhone bonjour services gets executed in safari.Using html interface i can import a file that is persisted into coredata. But i need to export the persisted data as a file from iphone to mac.In the html interface when i press a export button how to i show a save as dialog to save a exported file in my mac machine.

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but two great resources dealing with Bonjour on the iPhone and Mac can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PictureSharing/Introduction/Intro.html) and [here](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/).